# Neo4j check create result best practices

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am using Neo4J client for C#, and I am trying to create some unique nodes.
I've already created index and unique constraint in the database so I am sure that a duplication is not possible, but I want to detect when the creation of a node failed for unique constraint violation.

I am new with Neo4j but I see that common examples follow the (bad) practices to use ExecuteWithoutResults to execute this kind of request, so there is not any feedback of creation execution and I see also that there are not any exception generated if the creation failed.

What is the best practice to get result from a node creation command?
Following a piece of code showing how I create a node:

```
await client.Cypher                            
.Merge("(u:User { UserId: {userId}})")
.OnCreate()
.Set("u = {user}")
.WithParams(new
{
userId = user.UserId,                        
user
})
.ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fail to create the node, the exception would be thrown to the client.

However - your code uses `MERGE` - so that wouldn't happen anyway. Using `Neo4jClient` - there is no way to get the `X nodes created` feedback.

You could change your code to `.Return(u => u.As<User>())` and check the results, but that's about the only way I can think of.

Comment: Ok, no problem I will use Create instead of Merge, this generate an exception if the unique constraint is violated so I can get the feedback I need.
Thank you for the support Chris.

Comment: Exceptions are _bad_ things to be using for flow - if you want to know if it's there, do a `MATCH` beforehand, look up `apoc.do.when` and you should be able to see ways to return responses without needing exceptions. Exceptions should be exceptional, don't use them as 'if' statements!

Comment: Hi Chris, the idea is to propagate exception, not to catch it in a "if" statement and hide it, in this way I can at least allows clients to detect that the action has failed. Can you provide an example on how to use apoc.do.when for this specific case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually wanting - do you want to know if a node was created vs being updated? If I wanted that, I'd have a `DateCreated` on the node, and `ON CREATE` set that, `ON MATCH` I would set a `DateModified` property. When I return that node, I can check if they are different.